# Please set a non-empty phone number with #setPhoneNumber(), null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create an authentication function by phone number for firebase using flutter but got an error
*Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following PlatformException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth/phone/48cb18a1-934c-4daf-bd24-01285a43edb9:
PlatformException(error, The given phoneNumber is empty. Please set a non-empty phone number with #setPhoneNumber(), null, null)*

```
Future<void> VerifyNumber(String phoneNumb, String verificationId) async {
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumb,
    verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exc) async {
      if (exc.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
        print('Invalid phone number');
      } else
        print('e r r o r');
    },
    codeSent: (String verificationid, int? resendToken) {
      verificationId = verificationid;
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verId) {});}
```

Comment: Does the error goe away when you hard code a number: `phoneNumber: "44123456789",` ? Also, the parameter verificationId should not be necessary `VerifyNumber( ...String verificationId )`. Last but not least, please post the complete error stack / log as a text to find out which part of the code is actually causing the error.

Comment: error log                                                                                                      
 Exception caught by services library===============The following PlatformException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth/phone/48cb18a1-934c-4daf-bd24-01285a43edb9:
PlatformException(error, The given phoneNumber is empty. Please set a non-empty phone number with #setPhoneNumber(), null, null)